# How do I serve index.html by default in my http-server

Tags: angularjs, localhost, httpserver

I have created a basic AngularJS app in node environment. I am using http-server module for serving the files to browser. Everything is working fine except for the fact that I can't get to serve `index.html` by default when the server launches.

I checked out npm registry for more options to http server module, and also tried looking for a relevant question on SO but still not able to get what I desire.

Is it possible at all to specify the file to pick up while server starts.

My server basically starts at `localhost:8080` while I would like `localhost:8080/index.html`

My start script is `http-server -a localhost -p 8080 -c-1`. If I do something like `http-server -a localhost -p 8080 -c-1 index.html`, to my surprise it opens the `index.html` file but serves it on file protocol and not on `localhost`.

What am I doing wrong  here.

P.S. I visited Angular JS seed and there official example says `http-server -a localhost -p 8080 -c-1 ./app`. However, when I do this I get error **Windows can't find specified path**, although my structure is similar to the seed.

My structure:

```
dir
   --app.js
   --index.html
   --node_modules
   --package.json
```

Comment: are u using express framework?

Comment: No just a client based angular app

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are building your project first and generating an output `./dist` folder or similar.

Then try this command instead:

```
http-server -p 8080 ./dist -o http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

You are missing the `http://` in your url.

Comment: `-o` will open the specified document, not serve `a_dir/index.html` when `a_dir` is requested.

Comment: we can try this command, as default port is 8080 `http-server ./dist -o index.html`

Answer (score 1):

Add a `-f /index.html` or whatever the document is.
In my case for example:

```
http-server -c-1 -f /index.html
```

Comment: Doesn't work in the latest version, nor is it documented.

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved the problem was, I clicked the link through the CLI after doing `http-server [path]`.

In my case I ran `http-server .` (which has an `index.html` in the directory), then logs out this.

```
Starting up http-server, serving .

http-server version: 14.1.1

http-server settings:
CORS: disabled
Cache: 3600 seconds
Connection Timeout: 120 seconds
Directory Listings: visible
AutoIndex: visible
Serve GZIP Files: false
Serve Brotli Files: false
Default File Extension: none

Available on:
  http://192.168.8.133:8080
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.23.128.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Now I just used the link in the line below `Available on:` which is:

1. http://192.168.8.133:8080, works for me
2. http://127.0.0.1:8080, did not work for me, it download file instead
3. http://172.23.128.1:8080, works!

Such a weird behaviour of `http-server`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put you static file inside a new directory public. and run you server `http-server`

```
- app.js
-public
--index.html
-package.json
```

Comment: Did you restarted your server ? It will server default index.html file inside 
public dir and should work on both URL localhost:8080/index.html or localhost:8080

Comment: Yes I restarted my server. I hope you understand my question, I can get my application to work on localhost:8080/index.html by manually entering this url. What I want is it should itself open the browser at this url.

Comment: Okay Got It :)
Something similar here https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/231

Comment: This thread seems to address the same concern as I have, but if I try to use `-o localhost:8080/index.html` I get a error from Windows saying `The associated program is not installed`

Comment: https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/compare/master...craigmichaelmartin:master
If you want you can try this fork. I think this contain some fix for the same issue

Comment: I saw the provided code, it basically adds the argument to the opener url. As per the code `-o /index.html` should work fine, however this doesn't seem to be the case. The url is checked based on `typeof argv.o` so I tried using command as `http-server -o '/index.html' ". But even this doesn't wrk. Strange!!!